# jQuery select text in texbox on keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Got a bit of an issue with some jQuery. I'm trying to implement a data entry grid similar to the way excel navigates, using arrows up and down to traverse the column. I have script that runs on load to assign a rel attribute and unique ID to each text box, like so:

```
id="gScore_0" class="gScoreTB" rel=0
id="gScore_1" class="gScoreTB" rel=1
id="gScore_2" class="gScoreTB" rel=2
```

...and so forth. Then, I have the following handler:

```
    $('.gScoreTB').keydown(function (e) {

        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
            arrow = { left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40 };

        switch (keyCode) {

            case arrow.up:

                var str = $(this).attr('rel');
                str = parseInt(str) - 1;
                $("#gScore_" + str).focus();
                break;

            case arrow.down:
                //Set focus to the same cell next row
                var str = $(this).attr('rel');
                str = parseInt(str) + 1;
                $("#gScore_" + str).focus();

                break;
        }
    });
```

The theory is that the function adds/subtracts 1 from the ID and sets focus to that textbox. This all works great guns.

The problem is that I would like focus to change **and** any text in the box to all be selected. I've tried various combinations of using `.select()` on the text box in addition to `.focus()` but it isn't happening. I suspect it's something to do with events, but I'm no jQuery genius. Please help! Thanks

PS if anyone thinks what I've done is ridiculous I'm always up for criticism/improvements :-)

Comment: An improvement I see is how you get the keyCode - you dont need to check for keyCode and which - jQuery normalizes that so you dont have to explicitly check - just use "e.which" and it will always be correct. Also, for selecting text, try $("selector")[0].focus(); $("same_selector")[0].select();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so it turns out I just didn't code it all correctly. I needed to prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM, and also prevent the default action on the text box, as follows:

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

Or, as I later found out, can just use `return false;` which is the same as calling both the above. Easy! Once I added these in the event was stopped at the text box, so the other methods worked correctly. [Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409864/asp-net-jquery-stop-event-propogation-and-bubbling) to the other question I asked that answered the propagation issue.