# ASP.NET jQuery stop event propogation and bubbling

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using a bit of jQuery mixed in to an ASP.NET page and it doesn't seem to do what it ought to. I'm trying to re-assign the up and down arrows and enter key for text boxes so that the user can navigate up and down through the column (like in Excel). I have the event handler set up OK and it works, but I can't get the following part to work correctly:

```
e.preventDefault;
e.stopPropogation;
```

Particularly with the enter key, it is still submitting the form even with those two lines in. The only way I can get it working is with the following:

```
event.cancelBubble = true;
event.returnValue = false;
```

But from what I've read you shouldn't use those because the two jQuery methods are browser independant. Any help understanding all of this would be great :-)

**UPDATE**
I've got the handler in a block like this:

```
    //handles the up/down arrow behaviour of the score boxes
    $('.gScoreTB').keydown(function (e) {

        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.cancelBubble = true;
            event.returnValue = false;
        }

    });
```

Just a simple example to try and stop the enter key behaviour at the moment: will add keyCode == 38 and 40 for the other arrows once this is nailed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` are functions, so you should be doing:

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropogation();
```

But it's easier to just `return false` (which is the same as invoking both):

```
//handles the up/down arrow behaviour of the score boxes
$('.gScoreTB').keydown(function (e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I'm such an idiot leaving off the brackets, so simple! Good tip about return false; as well, cheers